# Array Method Help for Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

The goal is to return the sum of the numbers in the array using the `forEach` method. What am I doing wrong?

```
list = [6,7,1,3,1,17,4,12,1,5,0,13,15]

function totalPoint(array) {
  let sum = 0;
  array.forEach(function(number){
      sum += number
      return sum
  })
}

totalPoint(list)
```

It should have the same result as this:

```
function totalPoints(array){
  let sum = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    sum += array[i]
  }
return sum
}
```

Comment: use `reduce` it is easier.

`array.reduce((total, curr) => total+=curr, 0);`

Comment: when you do a forEach it doesnt return anything, what you should do is a normal for or use .reduce()

Comment: `reduce` is when you wanted an accumulated result from the array like sum, product, string concat with a filter and what not! in this use case definitely is easier as you don't have to maintain any variable.

Comment: For beginners, it somehow seems like a real problem, to realize, what function scope they are in, and accordingly, what the `return` counts for. So far, i assumed it's just people not really trying, but by the sheer amount of issues, i may have to reconsider. The problem is solely, that your `return` is for the callback of the `forEach`, and your `totalPoint` doesn't have any `return`. Simply move the `return` to the end of `totalPoint`.

Comment: It is no different than the for loop..... return needs to be outside the loop, exactly how you did it with the for loop.

Answer (score 3):

Using `forEach` loop `return sum` should be outside `forEach`:

```
list = [6,7,1,3,1,17,4,12,1,5,0,13,15]

function totalPoint(array) {
  let sum = 0;
  array.forEach(function(number){
      sum += number;
     
  })
  return sum;
}

totalPoint(list)
```

Answer (score 2):

For each does not return anything you need to return from function:

```js
const array = [6,7,1,3,1,17,4,12,1,5,0,13,15]

function totalPoint(array) {
  let sum = 0;
  array.forEach(function(number){
      sum += number
  })
  return sum

}

console.log(totalPoint(array))
```

Better way is to use `reduce`

```js
const array = [6,7,1,3,1,17,4,12,1,5,0,13,15]

function totalPoint(array) {
  return array.reduce((sum,number) => sum + number,0)

}

console.log(totalPoint(array))
```

Comment: I suggest using more descriptive names for the `reduce` callback. `(sum, number) => sum + number` is a lot more understandable than `(prev, next) => prev + next`.

Comment: Make senses. Updated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You return inside the callback (which is useless), but not at the end of the method.

```js
function totalPoint(array) {
  let sum = 0;
  array.forEach(function(number){
      sum += number
  });
  return sum;
}
list = [6,7,1,3,1,17,4,12,1,5,0,13,15]
console.log(totalPoint(list));
```

A simpler method would be to use `Array#reduce`:

```js
function totalPoint(array) {
  return array.reduce((acc,curr)=>acc + curr, 0);
}
list = [6,7,1,3,1,17,4,12,1,5,0,13,15]
console.log(totalPoint(list));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) for a simple solution:

```js
const numbers = [6, 7, 1, 3, 1, 17, 4, 12, 1, 5, 0, 13, 15];

const sum = numbers.reduce((runningTotal, number) => runningTotal += number, 0);

console.log(`The sum is ${sum}`);
```

Start with the `accumulator` initialized to `0` then, in the callback function, increment the accumulator by the next number in the array and return.